# Is there a reliable free cell solver?

Tags: solitaire, computer-ai, free-cell

I am trying to find a solution to game 9371310 and the online solver at

https://fc-solve.shlomifish.org/

instructions try to use **6 free cells when only 4 exist**. Here is where the instructions go terribly wrong.

Is there a more reliable solver out there?

[image]

Comment: I don't have that problem when I try to solve that board on that online solver.  What process did you follow?

Comment: Did you possibly select 6 from the drop down for number of freecells?

Comment: I get the OP's result when and only when switching "Freecells Number" from "Default" to "6". Just switch it back to "Default".

Answer (score 1):

### The solver you mention do solves this deal with 4 free cells.

For MS Freecell Deal #9371310

```
: TD 2S 8H 4S JC QC 6S 
: 2H 4C 7S 8S 9D KD 3D
: 5S 3C 9S 9H 7D AC KC
: 5D 7H 9C 5C AD 6D JD
: TC 4D 3H AS QD KS
: 3S 8C QS AH KH TS
: 2C QH 8D 4H JH JS
: 5H 2D 6C 6H TH 7C
```

Used the default settings, it solved it in few seconds:
[image]